# Prometheus label comparison with vector timestamp

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a vector like T@V(label="UTCtimestamp") with label = UTC timestamp string.. I want to find count of all vectors  which have  label like

T() - 1day <= label <= T()

where T() is timestamp at which Vector was pushed..

I am looking for some query like

V(T() - 1 day <= label <= T())[7d] where T() denotes the time at which vector was pushed

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, label values are opaque strings to Prometheus. What you'll want to do is put the timestamp as a value in another metric that has all the same labels (and no `label` label on either). Then you can check that and filter using `and`.

Also Prometheus doesn't push, it's all pull.

Comment: They might have a setup that pushes data - https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/